# Modelling Convection in Fluent

Tags: ansys, fluent

I am new to Ansys Fluent and am trying to model heat transfer through a system of fins. The analysis is in 3D.

I have set the Energy Equation as ON. The problem is that when I set heat loss by convection in the fins, a heat transfer coefficient is demanded by the software. However I am looking to evaluate the overall heat transfer coefficient of the fin system in the first place. Shouldn't the model be completely solved simply by knowing the material properties of the fin and the fluid and the velocity and temperature of fluid at the inlet?

Comment: is turbulent flow solved then or do we have to make assumptions?

Comment: I think a sketch or image would help a lot here. If you are trying to model some heat transfer to/from the fins that is external to the fluid domain (i.e. on a surface not in contact with the fluid), then FLUENT will expect you to input a heat transfer coefficient.